# Por que é difícil traduzir a palavra Saudade para outros idiomas?

Tags: ortografia, tradução-inglês, tradução

A palavra "Saudade" descreve uma mistura de sentimentos: perda, falta, distância e amor.

Por que é difícil traduzir-la para outros idiomas?

Comment: @Frank I forgot about the two-languages situation, that's definitely something to take in account. I'm still not very pleased with how this question is written though. Even if there's not a single word for it, it's not hard to translate to English a sentence with "saudade" in it.

Comment: @Molx I see your point; of course, one could edit to improve it. [That's what I did for the question you linked to :) ] I think the tags are a bit off, too: it doesn't seem related to orthography and there's no need to limit it to translation into English.

Comment: Não é duplicata, é apenas uma pergunta muito próxima. A outra pergunta está em inglês.

Comment: Ué, não estamos em um site de língua portuguesa? É claro que a comunidade Stack Exchange é mundial e existem pessoas do mundo todo que estão aqui neste site. Por isso a língua inglesa é necessária, em alguns momentos, para atingir a todos. Não considero, no entanto, que esta questão esteja duplicada, a menos que a questão original seja traduzida para português.

Comment: (Not sure if I understood your last sentence, but...) I think it's better to leave the other question alone. Who would take on responsibility for translating both the question and all of its answers? Also, it would make it quite a jumble to read. If you prefer not to take ownership and rep on this "duplicate", you could make it a community wiki: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: Eu não to certo que a "saudade" é uma palavra tão difícil pra traduzir. Acho que isso poderia ser mais um caso de "um mito romantico" do que realidade .)

Comment: Votei por fechar, porque mesmo as perguntas não sendo totalmente iguais, as respostas lá parecem explicar o motivo da "origem" o que explicaria a tal dificuldade. No entanto se discordar pode abrir uma questão no META para que todos possamos discutir.